# Sorting the array of strings on their lengths in Java , Using Maps, ascending order....

Tags: java, strings, sorting

I wrote the java method to answer this question :
**Write a Program to sort String on their length in Java? Your method should accept  an array of String and return a sorted array based upon the length of String**

So my questions:
1. Is my method efficient enough?
2. Can it be improved somehow?

```
 private static String[] sort(String [] string) {
    /*Local variables*/
    Map<String, Integer> map=new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    Map<String, Integer> mapCopy=new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    int [] lengthsArray=new int[string.length];
    String [] sortedStrings=new String[string.length];
    int counter1=0;
    int counter2=0;

    /* Store all the pairs <key,value>
     * i.e <string[i],string[i].length>
     */
    for(String s:string){
        map.put(s, s.length());
        lengthsArray[counter1]=s.length();//store all the lengths
        counter1++;

    }
    mapCopy=new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>(map);//make a copy of map
    Arrays.sort(lengthsArray);//sort the array of lengths

    /*
     * Sort array according to the array of lengths
     * by finding the matching value from the map 
     * then add it to the final string array,and then remove it from the map 
     */
    for(int item:lengthsArray){

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e:map.entrySet()){
            if(item==e.getValue()){
                sortedStrings[counter2]=e.getKey();
                counter2++;
                map.remove(e.getKey());
                break;
            }   
        }
    }

    map=mapCopy;
    System.out.println(map);//print map
    return sortedStrings;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use the Arrays.sort with Comparator to make this simple. just Override the comparator to compare the length of the array like this

```
public static String[] sortStrArray(String[] array){
   //sort arrays by length before returning
    Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            return Integer.compare(a.length(),b.length());//specifying compare type that is compare with length
        }
    });
     return array;
}
```

///Main Method here

```
String[] str = {"James","Ana","Michael","George","rose"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortStrArray(str)));
```

Output:

> [Ana, rose, James, George, Michael]

with Java 8

```
 public static String[] sortStrWithLam(String[] array){
    //sort arrays by length before returning
    Arrays.sort(array,(a,b) -> Integer.compare(a.length(),b.length()));
    return array;
}
```

Comment: The Java 8 solution could be written using [`Comparator.comparingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-).

Comment: @200_success yea that is another way too

Comment: `comparingInt` is a nice way to do it yes, you can do this with a one-liner: `Stream.of(array).sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: @Tunaki yea, with just a little 'return' to it is much compact